# Abnormally low frame rate on Vulkan tutorial project

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I followed the [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction) to create the program.

However, the frame rate is abnormally low.
Specifically, I started the program and monitored the frame rate using "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor". The frame rate was 6~8, which is clearly a low number.

I think this is a bug in my program. Please let me know how to solve this!

[This](https://github.com/SHiN-1213/vulkan_app/tree/main) is the source code of my project, which is almost the same as the sample program.

**I also ran the sample program published in the Vulkan tutorial without any changes, and the frame rate was 6~8, which is exactly the same result.**

I have confirmed that the correct GPU is selected using "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties", but I don't know what more to do. Can anyone help me?

- OS: Windows11
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
- Vulkan SDK: version 1.3.250.1
- GLFW: version 3.3.8 WIN64

Answer (score 1):

Self resolved.
The Vk_INSTANCE_LAYERS environment variable in windows was enabled.
By removing it from the list of environment variables, the program worked as intended.

Comment: What so bad was in it though to make it so slow?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).